# Как зайти по RDP через VPN с одинковой сетью сервера и клиента?

Tags: vpn, mikrotik, rdp, l2tp

Столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть сервер, на нем SQL адрес сети которого 192.168.1.4
Поднят VPN L2TP на микротике 10.1.0.0/24

Проблема:
Есть клиент1, у который не может достучаться до нас. Он соединен к нашему VPN. Его адрес 10.1.0.19
Стучится он по RDP к серверу SQL 192.168.1.4, и выдает ошибку. Но ньанс в том что в его роутере адресация его сети совпадает с нашей 192.168.1.0/24

Есть клиент2, ситуация та же но с ним все ок. VPN 10.1.0.10, но адресация его сети 192.168.100.0/24 и он спокойно ходит на SQL по адресу 192.168.1.4.

Поможет ли, если на клиент1 не меняя адресацию сети указать метрику на VPN соединение скажем 2?
Будет ли от этого толк.?

Еще не пробовал так как пока не могу зайти к нему и сделать.
У клиента1 не разрешается менять адресацию сети.

Может есть какие нибудь предположения что можно еще сделать?

Comment: Я бы всё же рекомендовал подумать о смене своей подсети — всё-таки 192.168.1.0/24 стоит по умолчанию почти в каждом первом роутере...

Comment: @andreymal  я бы с радостью но тут много подключение по статике и телефонов который забит адрес 192.168.1.4

Answer (score 0):

На клиенте виндовс нужно добавить маршрут 192.168.1.4/32

```
route add 192.168.1.4 255.255.255.255 10.1.0.1
```

после каждого подключения такой командой.

Автоматически его можно выдать по dhcp(микротик не умеет) или rip(в виндовс нужно включить службу) или прописать статически через программу cmak.

Метрика не поможет потому как у кдиента 192.168.1.0/24 скорее всего в скоупе он-линк.

Другое предложение: задай альтернативный адрес серверу. например, 10.2.0.2. Смаршрутизируй его на шлюзе опенвпн.

Ну или виртуальный ip с помощью NAT.

Comment: А можно ли указать в микротике маску адресу 10.1.0.0/32 указать? https://ibb.co/4mNk8bP у меня сейчас указана 24

Comment: можешь удаить этот маршрут - он не для этого

Comment: вообщем вижу только одно решение) после нового года перестроить в Офисе адресацию, дабы чтобы таких проблем не возникало. надеюсь что 30.0.30.0/24 никогда использоваться не будет у других компаний которые с нами заявязанны

Comment: @Игорь
`надеюсь что 30.0.30.0/24 никогда использоваться не будет` - никогда так не делайте. не используйте для внутренних адресов реально существующие, но не принадлежащие вам адреса

Comment: используй `10.138.0.0/24` например, накрайняк 100.... но не используй 30.0... это не вежливо и может привести к утечке данных